# EF-Entity configuration that has a List type property with items of an abstract class without considering a discriminator - EF

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with a configuration. Here is an example of what I want to do

I have this table structure, classic, header-detail, which I should not alter.
the `MusicalInstrument` table has a column called `Type` with the following possible values: Piano, Stringed

```
CREATE TABLE MusicalInstrument
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    [NAME]  VARCHAR(200),
    NumberStrings INT, -- SET WHEN TYPE = Stringed
    NumberOctaves INT, -- SET WHEN TYPE = Piano
    [Type] VARCHAR(200) -- Piano, Stringed
)

CREATE TABLE MusicalInstrumentItem
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    MusicalInstrumentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    StringIndex INT, -- SET WHEN MusicalInstrument.TYPE = Stringed
    OctaveIndex INT, -- SET WHEN MusicalInstrument.TYPE = Piano
)
```

I have created a class hierarchy for `MusicalInstrument`:

```
public abstract class MusicalInstrumentBase
{
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        protected abstract IReadOnlyCollection<MusicalInstrumentItemBase> ItemsBase { get; }

        public IReadOnlyCollection<MusicalInstrumentItemBase> Items { get { return this.ItemsBase; } }
}

public  class StringedInstrument: MusicalInstrumentBase
{
        private List<StringedInstrumentItem> _items = new List<StringedInstrumentItem>();

        public int NumberStrings { get; set; }

        protected override IReadOnlyCollection<MusicalInstrumentItemBase> ItemsBase => this.Items;

        public new IReadOnlyCollection<StringedInstrumentItem> Items => _items.AsReadOnly();

        public void PlayArpeggio(string staff) 
        {
            //implement
        }
}

public class PianoInstrument : MusicalInstrumentBase
{
        private List<PianoInstrumentItem> _items = new List<PianoInstrumentItem>();

        public int NumberOctaves { get; set; }

        protected override IReadOnlyCollection<MusicalInstrumentItemBase> ItemsBase => this.Items;

        public new IReadOnlyCollection<PianoInstrumentItem> Items => _items.AsReadOnly();

        public void PlayScale(string note)
        {
            //implement
        }
}
```

I have also created a class hierarchy for `MusicalInstrumentITEM`:

```
public abstract class MusicalInstrumentItemBase
{
        public Guid ID { get; set; }

        public Guid MusicalInstrumentID { get; set; }

        public abstract void FineTune();
}

public class StringedInstrumentItem : MusicalInstrumentItemBase
{
        public int StringIndex { get; set; }

        public override void FineTune()
        {
            // implement
        }
}

public class PianoInstrumentItem : MusicalInstrumentItemBase
{
        public int OctaveIndex { get; set; }

        public override void FineTune()
        {
            // implement
        }
}
```

I have been able to make the necessary configurations to store in the `MusicalInstrument` table, according to the hierarchy of classes shown, using `HasDiscriminator`, however, my problem is in the `MusicalInstrumentItem`, I don't know what to do to store it in the `MusicalInstrumentItem` table, respecting the model of data and class hierarchy: `MusicalInstrumentItemBase`, `StringedInstrumentItem` and `PianoInstrumentItem`.

Clearly the `MusicalInstrumentItem` table does not have a column to discriminate, the discriminatory column is in `MusicalInstrument`

Please someone could help me how to do it?

I am using EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5 with net5.0

Comment: Which version are you using ? The "classic" EF (v4, v5, v6) on the full, classic .NET framework, or **EF Core** on the newer, cross-platform .NET Core? You have tags for both which makes it impossible for us to know what you're really using and what options are available in your case .....

Comment: Sorry, I am using EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5 with net5.0